# Visual Studio 2010 always starts half sized

Tags: visual-studio-2010, settings, docking

Whenever VS2010 starts, the main window is half sized - the top half of the screen. I always maximize it vertically, but it still always starts half sized. I have 2 sub-windows undocked to either side; if I dock them inside the main window, then it remembers the correct size.

I have tried saving settings when it is full-sized, and importing them again, but it makes no difference. Any ideas?? Thanks!